# Using tool at home made to work in cigarette socket?

Tags: electrical

I have a tool that only works by connecting its "plug" to my [car cigarette lighter socket](http://articlesforwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Car-Cigarette-Lighter.jpg).

How can I use this tool at home? Is there an adapter that will let me use it somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for *120V 12V cigarette lighter adapter*. If your home electricity is 240V (i.e., most places outside USA/Canada) then look for *240V 12V cigarette lighter adapter*. Some adapters will, like laptop chargers and other equipment, handle a range 110V - 240V, 50/60 Hz.

You'll find more of the reverse (to run 120VAC equipment using your car's 12VDC) but there are plenty like [this adapter on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LX5LRP9). I recommend getting one that is UL listed if possible and make sure it can supply the power (watts) your tools need.

Comment: I have a feeling rbhat is in the USA. But I could be wrong - and the next person looking for an answer might not be in the USA anyway. I'll edit.

Comment: If it's used infrequently the portable jump starters with lighter sockets pulls reasonable double duty. Jumps stubborn engines, runs a tire inflator long enough to fill the occasional floaty toy, allows using phone chargers during power outages, etc.